# Approach for switching weapons?

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm developing my first multiplayer game in Unity3D using PhotonNetworking. You can think of it as a 2D-Arena Game, basically "Overwatch in 2D".

I have come to the point where the Player can switch between different heroes via a Hero-Menu (accessable at spawning point).

This is achieved in the following way:

**Game starts:**

- load table "hero_data" from my SQL database and store the values in my `<int, data>Dictionary`, where "data" is a `struct{int ID, healthpoints, weaponType...}`
- load table "weapons_data" from SQL db, store it in Dict..... (same process)

**Hero switching:**

Switching the hero happens by **calling an RPC** to let everyone know the hero was switched and basically **get the values** at a specific index of the **hero_data-dictionary**
This seems to work flawlessly.

However, **each hero has its own weapon** (should be a child object of the hero) and I don't know which approach I should take for switching the weapon.

**Facts:**

- weapons_data (dictionary) consists of `int 'damage', 'range', 'magazine', 'shooting_frequency', 'splash_damage' ...`
- I consider **at least 3 weapon types**: *raycast* (laser), *projectile instantiation* (rockets), *melee* (collision check)
- the **weapon types share common fields** like `'damage', 'range', 'magazine' ...`
- Game contains about **10 heroes**

Developing the different firing types is not the issue!
What would be a performant way to switch weapons?

**What I thought of already:**

- Base class `Weapon : Monobehaviour{}` which inherits a `virtual Shoot(){raycast-firing?}`

inheriting classes e.g.: `ProjectileShooting : Weapons{}` with an `override Shoot(){projectile instantiation?}`

- The mentioned RPC "SwitchHero" could include a line that kinda goes like `if(hero.weaponType = 1){ weaponObject.AddComponent<ProjectileShooting>(); }`
- Or should Weapon.cs have a method instantiating the ProjectileShooting class?
- Or create an Array containing a weapon for every single hero? (I personally don't like this approach, since there are about 10 heroes but some of them have the same weapon type, just different damage and magazine values)

What do you think about the approaches? How would you design a multiplayer (hero +) weapon switch?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with each hero having its own collection of weapons, since they individually need to have things like ammunition count tracked. Does this approach pose a problem to you? Using inheritance/interfaces here is also a must, since you certainly don't want to bother with detecting the exact type of weapon when firing it - let the weapon determine how it's going to behave when it's told to fire.

Comment: I just did some research on interfaces (didn't know about them and their logic). Correct me if I'm wrong: You suggest me to create a weapon (each hero has only 1 unique weapon) perhaps as a GO for each Hero? Example: Hero A has Weapon RocketLauncher. Attached to the Rocketlauncher there is "RocketLauncher.cs": `RocketLauncher : Weapon, IShootable, IReloadable {...}` ?

Comment: I might even suggest multiple GameObjects, one for each weapon under a hero - then disable/enable them and update your reference to the active one as you switch weapons for a Hero. Then yep - you'll just interact with the active weapon through its interfaces, so you won't need to know what type it is to tell it to shoot/reload/etc.